# Chain together two CompletableFutures that each return Lists

Tags: java, functional-programming, stream, future, completable-future

I'm having a hard time figuring this out and can use some help from those more experienced and knowledgeable than I am.

The basic problem is that I need to fetch a List of Objects, and then for each Object returned, fetch some details, and stitch the details into the Object.  I'd like to be efficient about this; I need to get the List of DataFiles first, but once I have that, I can make the calls to get their Tags all at the same time, and then wait for all of the getTags responses to come back before I process them.

```
public class DataFile {
    // DataFileDao returns all DataFile properties, except Tags
    private List<Tags> tags;
    ...
}
```

I just cannot figure out how to do this functionally using CompletableFutures and streams.  Here's the basic code I'm using, though, and if someone could help me to the finish line, I'd greatly appreciate it:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<DataFile>> getDataFilesWithTags() {

    final CompletableFuture<List<DataFile>> dataFileFutures = this.dataFileDao.getDataFiles()
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body).thenApply(this::toDataFileList);

    final CompletableFuture<List<List<Tag>>> tagFutures = dataFileFutures
        .thenCompose(dataFiles -> HttpUtils.allAsList(dataFiles.stream()
            .map(file -> this.tagDao.getLatestTagsForDataFile(file.getId())).collect(toList())));

    final CompletableFuture<List<DataFile>> filesWithTags = dataFileFutures.thenCombine(tagFutures,
        (files, tags) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                files.get(i).setTags(tags.get(i));
            }

            return files;
        });

    return fileWithTags;
}

/**
 * Transforms a generic {@link List} of {@link CompletableFuture}s to a {@link CompletableFuture} containing a
 * generic {@link List}.
 *
 * @param futures the {@code List} of {@code CompletableFuture}s to transform
 * @param         <T> the type of {@link CompletableFuture} to be applied to the {@link List}
 * @return a {@code CompletableFuture} containing a {@code List}
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code futures} is null
 */
public static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> allAsList(final List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    Validate.notNull(futures, "futures cannot be null");
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
            .thenApply(ignored -> futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

There's gotta be a cleaner, more functional way to do this, right?

An abstract representation of what I'd like to do:

```
public class ParentObject {

    // RETURNED BY ParentObjectDao.getAllParentObjects()
    private String id;

    // *NOT* RETURNED BY ParentObjectDao.getAllParentObjects()
    // MUST BE RETRIEVED BY MAKING SUPPLEMENTAL CALL TO ParentObjectDao.getParentsChildren(String parentObjectId)
    private List<ChildObject> details;
}

public class ChildObject {

    private String id;
    private String description;
}

public class ParentObjectDao {

    public CompletableFuture<List<ParentObject>> getAllParentObjects();

    public CompletableFuture<List<ChildObject>> getChildrenForParent(String parentObjectId);
}

public class Something {

    private final ParentObjectDao dao;

    public List<ParentObject> getParentObjectsWithChildren(){

        // PSEUDO-LOGIC
        final List<ParentObject> parentsWithChildren = dao.getAllParentObjects()
            .thenApply(List::stream)
            .thenCompose(parentObject -> dao.getChildrenForParent(parentObject.getId()))
            .thenApply(parentObject::setChildren)
            .collect(toList);

        return parentsWithChildren;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, with reference to classes that we don't know what are supposed to do. Why don't you create a simpler example that demonstrates the same concept, so that it is clearer for us to understand?

Comment: Is your intention to create one asynchronous chain of calls? or is your intention to handle each `DataFile` on separate threads (and separate `CompletableFuture`s?) Your code as it is now is handling the whole list of data files in just one `CompletableFuture`, so the only parallelism you have is with the main thread. Might as well encapsulate all of it in one method.

Comment: i'd like to do that latter: handle each TagDao.getTags(String dataFileId) call in its own separate asynchronous CompletableFuture, so that I can make all the tag calls at once, then sequence those results into each DataFile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have is not really parallelising much. You are only handling one `CompletableFuture` at a time, chaining operations to it. So if you have 1000 data files, they will still be processed in sequence.

Also, from a design and readability point of view, the `CompletableFuture` is operating at too much of a low level (do you really need to chain `thenApply(HttpResponse::body).thenApply(this::toDataFileList)` can't you encapsulate the transformation properly and have the `CompletableFuture` just represent one method?)

Using your pseudo code, what about something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<List<ParentObject>> populateAsync(List<ParentObject> parents) {

  //get the children of each parent in parallel, store the futures in a list
  List<CompletableFuture<ParentObject>> futures = 
    parents.stream() 
           .map(parent ->
                   parentObjectDao.getChildrenForParent(parent.getId())
                                  .thenApply(parent::setChildren))  //assuming setChildren returns the parent object
           .collect(Collectors.toList()); //we need this stream terminal operation to start all futures before we join on the first one

  //wait for all of them to finish and then put the result in a list
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                                     futures.stream()
                                            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());    
}
```

You would then be able to do something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<List<ParentObject>> getAllParentObjects()
          .thenApply(this::populateAsync)
```

(I might have some syntax errors because I just wrote it here directly, but you should get the idea).